# Auto-Publication with Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook

I have a client who has recently raised a problem of self publishing articles facebook. The client has created his application that seems correctly configured but the publication does not appear on his page. The message sent back by the facebook API is the following: **(# 100) Parameters of the URL have the ability to specify the picture, name, thumbnail or description.**
The Oauth connection is running correctly, the problem is with the publication.

To perform tests on my side, I became an administrator on its facebook application and then filled in my own page created for a long time already. No problem to publish on my personal page with the API facebook. I created a second page always with the same account then changed the url of the page on which to publish and I reproduce the problem. There seems to be a problem checking the user's rights on the page.

While searching on Google, I could find that is a security implemented on version 2.11 of the API with the domains but I did not find any way to solve my problem. Does anyone have a solution? Why I can publish on old pages but not on new pages created from the same account.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and sorry for bad english :)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification

Comment: Thanks for your link, i don't have access to business manager for the client. I try to add meta balise fb:pages but without success. <meta property="fb:pages" content="881169995387554">

The url where i want to publish is https://www.facebook.com/Test-autopublication-881169995387554/
I can publish on this page : https://www.facebook.com/John-Rand-Page-409396475922679/ without problem. The two pages are created by the same user.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you refreshed the cache/checked your implementation via the debug tool?